# react native can't get current state value if destruct state

Tags: react-native

I'm calling axios request to get contacts from API and then i set the state with the current response.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      contacts: [],
      page: 1,
    };
  }

async getContacts() {
const {page} = this.state;
try {
  let response = await axios.get(`${API.URL}/contacts?page=${page}`);
  const result = response.data['hydra:member'];
  this.setState({contacts: JSON.stringify(result[1], null, '  ')});
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error.message);
}
```

}

```
async componentDidMount() {
await this.getContacts();
console.log('###############################');
console.log(this.state.contacts);
console.log('###############################');
```

}

the console log show me the state value :

```
###############################
[Wed May 27 2020 16:00:17.810]  LOG      {
  "civility": "female",
  "lastName": "Alexandre",
  "phone": "+1437390902042"
}
[Wed May 27 2020 16:00:17.812]  LOG      ###############################
```

but when i destruct the state like this :

```
async componentDidMount() {
const {contacts} = this.state;
await this.getContacts();
console.log('###############################');
console.log(contacts);
console.log('###############################');
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are destructuring your state before calling `setState` that's why you get an empty array. You should call `getContacts` before destructuring `contacts`

```
async componentDidMount() {
  await this.getContacts(); // getContacts should be called before
  const {contacts} = this.state;
  console.log('###############################');
  console.log(contacts);
  console.log('###############################');
}
```

---

**Edit:** I see that you don't know destructuring utility so I'll try to explain it to you with a little example.

Destructuring allows to extract properties from json objects and arrays and assign them into variables. This feature allows you to make your code minimal and easily readable.

Here's a little example: Assuming I have my state object like this:

```
{
  userInfos: {
    username: 'user1',
    email: 'example@xyz.com'
  },
  profileInfos: {
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

If I want to access username and email from `userInfos`, I should write `this.state.userInfos.username` and `this.state.userInfos.email`. Imagine if I use those properties 3 or 4 times in a function or in render method, my code will grow and will be less readable.

As a solution I can assign userInfos properties to variables so I can write:

```
const username = this.state.userInfos.username;
const email = this.state.userInfos.email;
```

Here I can use directly username and email with this approach, but the problem here is if I had 10 properties in userInfos then I should write 10 variable declarations.

From ES6, we can use destructuring assignement. We can now assign username and email to variables in a single line

```
const { username, email } = this.state.userInfos;
```

I hope my example was clear, you can search about destructuring in google and you will find more clear explanations and examples.

Comment: so what's the difference between this.state.contacts and   {contacts} =this.state

Comment: You can use any method you want there's no difference. I edited my answer to explain destructuring utility. Hope this help you!